# Django-rules setup issue: has_perm always False for custom user model

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-rules

I am new to Django. I have been trying to set up [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules) with a custom user model but keep getting a 404 when trying to access the page. Here is how the setup looks:

Custom user model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'rules.permissions.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'rules.apps.AutodiscoverRulesConfig',
]
```

rules.py

```
@rules.predicate
def is_organisation_member(user, organisation):
    """Check if user is an active organisation member"""
    m = get_if_exists(
        OrganisationMember,
        user=user,
        organisation=organisation,
        organisation__state=Organisation.LifecycleState.ACTIVE
    )
    if not m:
        return False
    if not m.is_active:
        return False
    return True

rules.add_perm('organisations.member',  (is_authenticated & is_active & is_organisation_member))
```

views.py

```
def get_organisation_by_slug(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return get_object_or_404(Organisation, workspace_name=kwargs['workspace'])

@permission_required('organisations.member', fn=get_organisation_by_slug)
def OrganisationView(request, workspace):
    # ...
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # ...

    # organisation
    path('<str:workspace>', v.OrganisationView, name="organisation-show"),
    # ...
]
```

According to the debug, `is_organisation_member` returns **True**, but the user still gets a 404 error when trying to view the page (without django-rules `permission_required` decorator the page works). Any ideas why am I getting a 404 response?

Comment: Would you mine showing us the full error as you usually get this error if your urls.py is wrong or if you do GET instead of POST or something like that?

Comment: Sure: ```Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc1
Raised by: bb.views.OrganisationView
Not found

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.``` The url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc1. abc1 is the name of the org and it's in the database. The url works when I remove the decorator.

Comment: could you please add your urls.py

Comment: Sure, done. Thanks!

Comment: @AyanSh thanks for reviewing the question, when you asked about the urls.py, I started wondering if the issue was actually in a different place and started tweaking the code in different places.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah - thanks! The fix is below. :)

Answer (score 0):

> without django-rules's `permission_required` decorator the page works

That was only half true! It worked when the generator was removed **and** existing test data was present. But when the query returned nothing, the 404 error showed up.

I have incorrectly assumed the issue was in setting up rules but after removing the decorator the error still persisted. I didn't see that error before because I always had test data auto-generated (a list of projects) but not this time. So, after reviewing the view function, I realised I was raising a 404 error when the project query was returning an empty list:

```
@permission_required('organisations.member', fn=get_organisation_by_slug)
def OrganisationView(request, workspace):

    # Query strings:
    # Extract 'tab' value appended to url as
    # ?tab=projects
    tab = request.GET.get('tab', '')
    
    # Get organisation
    try:
        o = Organisation.objects.get(workspace_name=workspace)
    except Organisation.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Not found.")

    if tab == 'projects':
        # Get project list 
        try:
            p = Project.objects.filter(organisation__workspace_name=workspace) \
                .order_by('-created_at')
        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Not found")
    else:
        raise Http404("Not found...") # ERROR CAUSED BY THIS LINE
        # To fix the error, I have removed the above line and added the below query
        # p = Project.objects.filter(organisation__workspace_name=workspace) \
        #     .order_by('-created_at')

    # Set context 
    context = {
        'o': o,
        'projects': p
    }

    return render(request, 'bb/home.html', context)
```

As I was confident my view was okay, I didn't post the complete function making it hard for anyone else to pickup the error. I realised the error was in the view after adding `has_perm(self, perm, obj=None): return True` to the User model but still getting a 404 error.